# i am not able to read the entity message from javax.ws.rs.core.Response in java client

Tags: java, jax-rs, restful-authentication

hi i created the restful server and client using jax-rs in apache tomee.i am returning status and entity from server and i am reading successful but i am not able to read the entity from response object.

This is my code in server side Rest.

```
@Path("/login")
@POST
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response login(String user,@Context HttpServletRequest  request,@Context HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    int sc=200;
    //this above status code i am changing base on the error
    return  javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(sc).entity("error on server side").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
}
```

i created client for invoking the above service in java

```
   Response response=WebClient.create("http://myserver:8080/Snefocare").path("/User/login").post(user);
System.out.println("the status is "+response.getStatus());          
System.out.println("the metadata is "+response.getEntity());
System.out.println("the entity "+response.getEntity());
```

output of above code

```
    the status is 200
    the metadata is sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@294c4c55
    the entity sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@294c4c55
```

i do not know why entity is printing in some other formate.

Answer (score 0):

The response entity is an `InputStream`, which should be obvious from this line;

```
the entity sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@294c4c55
```

Have you tried reading this stream?